# Meta analysis for coefficients/betas from multivariate linear models in python or r

Tags: r, multiple-regression, python, linear, meta-analysis

I have 3 studies. For each study I perform the following multivariate linear regression:

y ~ x1 + x2 + x3

I want to perform a meta analysis on the coefficient for x1 to understand the true effect of x1 on y across all studies.

Ideally, in python/R.

Would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/metafor may help you.